# Solve $a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 - 6abc = 1 $

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

From time to time I ask about units in Cubic fields.  I [noticed](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf) for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ I get an analogue of the Pell equation:

$$ \det \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a & 2c & 2b \\ b & a & 2c \\ c & b & a \end{array} \right] = a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 - 6abc = 1 $$

without citing the Dirichlet unit theorem.

---

Clearly the answers are $a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} = (1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4})^n$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (since we this number is unit we can have negative exponent.

Except, I have no way of ruling out other families of solutions.  And is there any constructive way of solving this, i.e. without taking a wild guess?

In the $\text{deg}=2$ case (such as $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$) there is an answer using the pell eq and the continued fraction $\sqrt{2} = [1;\overline{2}]$.  Can we do something analogous here?

---

There are continued fractions you can do on triples of numbers.  I think the first step here is:

$$ (1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}) \to (1, \sqrt[3]{2}-1, \sqrt[3]{4}-1) \to \dots $$

not sure what the smallest number is here.  I wonder if the familiar story from Pell works here?  Does this euclidean algorithm repeat?  Maybe this does not lead to finding units.

---

Since I am basically asking for a <del>walk-through</del> explication of the Dirichlet unit theorem, there are numerous resources that discuss this in generality.

[Avoiding Minkowski's theorem in algebraic number theory.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19021/avoiding-minkowskis-theorem-in-algebraic-number-theory)

[What is your favorite use of the pigeonhole principle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62565/what-is-your-favorite-application-of-the-pigeonhole-principle)

Another one that comes to mind is Hasse's **Lectures on Number Theory** if you have an English copy of the book.

---

The equation $z^3 - 2 = (z - \sqrt[3]{2})(z - \omega\sqrt[3]{2})(z - \omega\sqrt[3]{2}) = 0$ has a real root and a complex conjugate pair of roots.  So the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ has a real embedding and a complex embedding.

Then define an embedding $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \to \mathbb{R}^3$

$$ (a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4})(a+ b\omega\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega^2\sqrt[3]{4})
(a+b\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega\sqrt[3]{4})
= a^3 + 2b^3 + 4c^3 - 6abc$$

This is not a familiar norm since it's cubic.  And then define a region:

\begin{eqnarray}
|a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}| &=& c_1 \\
(a+ b\omega\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega^2\sqrt[3]{4})
(a+b\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega\sqrt[3]{4}) &\leq & c_2^2
\end{eqnarray}

The second equation defines the interior an conic section.

$$ a^2 + \sqrt[3]{2}b^2 + 2\sqrt[3]{4}c^2 + ab + ac + 4bc \leq c_2^2  $$

I am following arguments [here](http://wstein.org/129/lectures/day10/day10.pdf) and [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/unittheorem.pdf) trying to get the case $K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

If $c_1 c_2^2 < A$ can we show there is a lattice point in $\mathcal{O}_K$ inside this 3D region?  This should work in a similar way for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{m})$ maybe the constant $A$ changes.

Comment: You could possibly go through the proof of the unit theorem in this special case.

Comment: we may try to prove that for a unit $x$ the unit $x(\sqrt[3]{2}-1)^{\pm 1}$ has smaller `something', and so make a descent

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you want a proof without citing Dirichlet's unit theorem and without going through the usual proof of Dirichlet's unit theorem in this instance?

Comment: [Sorry to see that you deleted your answer; the references you gave
are indeed useful, and for the record I did not downvote your answer.
Since the references are no longer generally visible, I copy them here:
Example 1 in Section V.3 of Fröhlich-Taylor: Algebraic number theory 
(Cambridge University Press, 1991) and SAGE using the commands
**K.<a> = NumberField(x^3 - 2)** //
**K.maximal_order().basis()** //
**UnitGroup(K).gens_values()**
BTW GP will also do this quickly, e.g. **bnfinit(x^3-2)[8][5]** reports
that $x-1$ (i.e. $\root3\of2-1$) is a generator of the units mod $\pm1$.]

Comment: I think explicating a (simple and standard) proof is not a research level question. At any rate, for a quick proof that $1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}$ generates all solutions, see Example 1 in Section V.3 of Fröhlich-Taylor: Algebraic number theory (Cambridge University Press, 1991).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks for your support. I understand those who downvoted. Amusingly, I also copied back here my textbook reference, and I hit "enter" 10 seconds after you.

Comment: You seem to be unfamiliar with algebraic number theory, so I suggest that you cover the basics first (e.g. read through Fröhlich-Taylor). In particular, $a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc$ is equal to the norm of $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$ (while you say it is not a familar norm).

Comment: Also, your embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not correct (since you should end up with a triple of real numbers instead of a product of three complex numbers). A correct embedding would map $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$ to the triple $(a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4},{\rm Re}(a+ b\omega\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega^2\sqrt[3]{4}),{\rm Im}(a+ b\omega\sqrt[3]{2}+c\omega^2\sqrt[3]{4}))\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481203/units-in-cube-root-system   for an elementary approach to this problem.